# Saber se um período de tempo (hora) faz sentido

Tags: javascript

O usuário vai digitar um período em horas e a mesma tem que fazer sentido. Por exemplo, ele pode dizer que será cobrado uma taxa de plantão entre 22:00 e 6:00 , isso pode, mas não pode dizer por exemplo que o plantão é entre 04:00 e 3:00 obviamente. A solução que encontrei foi a seguinte, mas está muito complexa, tenho certeza que da pra fazer melhor, o javascript não tem uma função pronta para comparar horas? Obrigado.

```
          var mensagem='tudo ok';
          var hi='10:00';
          var hf='11:30';

          var hora_inicial=hi.substring(0,2);
          var hora_final=hf.substring(0,2);
          var minuto_inicial=hi.substring(3,5);
          var minuto_final=hf.substring(3,5);

         var mesmo_grupo=0; //saber se estão no mesmo grupo am ou pm

         if (hora_inicial >= 12 && hora_inicial<=24 && hora_final>=12 && hora_final<=24 )
         mesmo_grupo=1;

         if (hora_inicial >=0 && hora_inicial<=12 && hora_final >=0 && hora_final<=12)
         mesmo_grupo=1;

           if (mesmo_grupo==1)  //se  estão no mesmo am ou pm a primeira hora tem que ser menor que a segunda
         {

            if (hora_inicial > hora_final)
             {
             continua=0;
             mensagem='Reveja a hora. ';            
             }

         }
alert(mensagem);
```

Comment: Por que não pode dar 4 às 3 se o cara pode virar um dia fazendo plantão?

Comment: Na verdade ele atende pessoas em um horário de plantão e cobra uma taxa, por exemplo, um médico te atende até as 22:00 por R$300 a consulta e das 22:00 até as 6:00 por R$500 por cobrar uma taxa de R$200 no plantão. Matematicamente faria sentido a tua exposição mas na prática não.

Answer (score 1):

O que eu faria é definir que um plantão deve ser de no máximo X horas, e validar se o resulado da subtracao das horas é maior que o Limite do plantão.

```js
//Retorna true se válido
function validaPlantao(hora1, hora2)
{
    var plantaoLimite = 12; 
    var hora = 60000 * 60; 
    
    hora1 = hora1.split(":");
    hora2 = hora2.split(":");
    
    var d = new Date();
    var data1 = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate(), hora1[0], hora1[1]);
    var data2 = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate(), hora2[0], hora2[1]);
    var resultado = (data2 - data1) / hora ; 
    return resultado < plantaoLimite;
};

console.log(validaPlantao('07:00', '18:00'));
console.log(validaPlantao('08:30', '19:00'));
console.log(validaPlantao('00:00', '23:00'));
```